# Detect collision with object in nsarray / nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I made a little prototype game and so far everything works fine, collision also. Now I want to optimize some stuff. I have creeps with different properties and I want to put them in an array. But I don't know how to check the objects in an array for collision because the command is expecting a SKnode I guess. Here I am defining the creeps and the array:

```
SKSpriteNokde *creep1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_creepTexture1];
[creep1 setScale:1];
creep1.position = CGPointMake( 10, y )
creep1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:creep1.frame.size];
creep1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[CreepPair addChild:creep1];

SKSpriteNokde *creep2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_creepTexture2];
[creep2 setScale:2];
creep2.position = CGPointMake( 50, y + creep1.size.height);
creep2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:creep2.frame.size];
creep2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[CreepPair addChild:creep2];
..

SKSpriteNode *Level1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:creep1,creep2,creep3,creep4,nil];
```

Here I am checking for collision and this works:

```
if ([creep1 intersectsNode:Player] {
    creep1.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Lost 1 Life!");
 }
```

But I want to check all creeps like this:

```
if ([Level1.allobjects intersectsNode:Player] {
    creep1.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Lost 1 Life!");
}
```

The last code obviously don't work, but how can I manage this?

Comment: As you are already using physicBodies, is there any reason why you are not using the built in collision detection instead?

Comment: Now that you're asking.. No. I just looked it up. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked for me! Built in collision detection.

Comment: You're welcome, it really is the way to go with the least amount of fuzz. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
for (SKSpriteNokde *creep in Level1)
{
    if ([creep intersectsNode:Player] {
        creep.hidden = YES;
        NSLog(@"Lost 1 Life!");
    }
}
```

here I assume that Level1 is array.